# Change default path to chrome execution in karate-chrome to use chromium

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, karate

I am using the Karate framework to do UI testing.
But the PATH /usr/bin/chromium-browser is not take in account.

How we can change the default location of the chrome executable to use chromium?

Comment: yes. the options supports an `executable` setting, please see the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-core#configure-driver